# React proptypes with oneof object key

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I call two endpoints that respond with inconsistent JSON structure.

In the **1<sup>st</sup>**, JSON returned looks like this:

```json
{
payinData: [{...}, {...}, ...],
amount: 3000
}
```

And in the **2<sup>nd</sup>**:

```json
{
payInData: [{...}, {...}, ...],
amount: 34500
}
```

**The problem lies** in the casing of object keys, i.e **payinData** in 1<sup>st</sup> is different from **payInData** in 2<sup>nd</sup>.

I want to use the same react component for data coming from these endpoints. I can handle this inconsistency in my code logic but don't know how to do the same in props validation with [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types).

I have tried to do this:

```js
MyComponent.propTypes = {
dataPayload: Proptypes.shape({
    [Proptypes.oneOf(["payInData", "payinData"])]: Proptypes.arrayOf(Proptypes.shape({})),
    amount: Proptypes.number
  }),
}
```

But I get linting errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think our priority here should be:

1. To modify the API server to keep the responses unified
2. To modify the incoming requests (With a middleware or something like that)
3. To try to fix typescript declarations

Have you considered the first 2 options?

Comment: I do not have control over the server and I am not using typescript